# Dealing with [acm] and friends

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I stumbled upon [acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm) by chance and saw to my astonishment

> THIS TAG SHOULD NOT BE USED. Instead use [acm-java-libraries], [acm-icpc], [programming-competitions], [usb] or [appfabric] as applicable

Apparently it is too ambiguous, simultaneously meaning

> - The [Association of Computing Machinery](http://www.acm.org/), who are:
>
>   - organisers of the [ACM-ICPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACM_International_Collegiate_Programming_Contest) ([acm-icpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm-icpc)) and ICFP [programming-competitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-competitions) (and others, past and present)
>   - creators of the [ACM Java Libraries](http://jtf.acm.org/) ([acm-java-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm-java-libraries))
> - The [Audio Compression Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([microsoft-acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-acm)), an audio codec API that is part of Microsoft Windows.
> - A standard for [usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usb) CDC devices
> - ACM.EXE, which is an access control utility for use with Microsoft's [appfabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appfabric)

The first two are burninated tags.

Yet 61 questions are tagged with [acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm). It is obviously misleading and causing some harm, but it could be argued it serves as a (malfunctioning) signpost. What do we do with the tag? (Hint: Trogdor)

Comment: Yes, this should be burned. I’m including it in [this list of programming competition metatags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396289/now-its-time-to-judge-competitive-coding/399127#399127).

Answer (score 3):

This is now done.

I've retagged the questions that were on topic but were referencing USB, Amazon's Certificate Manager, Heroku's Certificate Manager, the Java ACM libraries, etc. where appropriate. I closed anything that was off topic, often deleting the post as it was not going to be salvageable anyway.