# Now it's time to judge [competitive-coding]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. That a question is about a program for a competitive coding is irrelevant to the question itself. It is unambiguous to the point that competitive coding does not have more than one meaning, but I think that it's a meta tag.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Stack Overflow is about programming (or coding), so yes.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   None whatsoever. The question would be answered the same way irrespective of whether it had this tag or not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   It depends. Competitive coding often has different criteria in different places.

[competitive-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitive-coding) has 83 questions, 22 of them closed.

Burn!

Comment: This has less than 50 questions, so we could possibly use the fast burninate process. I'd gladly second it as a trusted user. Especially since the usual process appears to be on hold.

Comment: @ErikA Sure, let's do it then. Just one question: How?

Comment: Let's leave it for a day since it's on meta anyway, and see if we have no objections tomorrow. If we start burninating, we'd probably want to take a pass at closing all the questions that should be closed, check if people in SOCVR want to help once we put all those into the queue, and retag questions that are on-topic and don't need to get closed.

Comment: Side note: if you are editing/looking at questions in this tag please make sure *not to comment* like "answers to this are not allowed by competition rules" as cheating by OP is not concern on SO. Indeed competition is free to file "DMCA takedown" request... but answering can't be blocked by external rules.

Comment: Indeed, moderators regularly handle flags that state a question should be deleted because it concerns an active contest. We always decline such flags because moderators are not here to police the rules of a completely different entity. We are not going to verify if the claim is true or if the competition is really still active or if there are possible exceptions and nuances to the rules that might actually permit the question to be posted anyway. Competition rules are treated the same as licensing terms and copyright violation claims, in that respect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that's not what the question is about. The tag is a meta-tag and provides no value to the question.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I was not implying anything about the tag. I was following up on Alexei’s comment. It’s *context*.

Comment: @ErikA No objections.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Great! I have time to contribute substantially tomorrow, but you can get started if you want to. Just retag the questions that should remain on SO, close the ones that shouldn't, and try to get the closed questions that won't roomba deleted (e.g. those with accepted answers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've torched it. Almost every single post with the tag was off-topic (lacking an MCVE, or way too broad).

I've also found that [acm-icpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm-icpc) has re-emerged, with 13 questions, another meta tag of the same ilk. It has been torched too.

I've also burned through the following related tags (each has only a smallish number of posts, 85 or fewer):

- [onlinejudge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onlinejudge)
- [google-foobar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-foobar)
- [uva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uva)
- [acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm) (see [Dealing with [acm] and friends](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360090/dealing-with-acm-and-friends))
  (Note that `uva` is actually related to CUDA GPU universal virtual addressing and people asking questions about the [UVa online judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UVa_Online_Judge) have hijacked it; I renamed it to [cuda-uva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda-uva)).

This is all part of our [Recurring Cycle of Competition Meta Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler/284302#284302), or *RCCMT*. I should probably trademark that abbreviation.

Comment: Is it possible to blacklist these?