# We need to de-leet [leetcode]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) tag has been gaining popularity of late, but it doesn't make sense for pretty much the same reasons that [the hackerrank tag didn't make sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866/the-challenge-of-burninating-hackerrank). There are about 86 questions tagged at the time of writing.

---

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It tags questions from [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode), it doesn't describe the *contents* of the questions, only its origin.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes, as long as the question doesn't ask about the site itself.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. Well, except that the OP is usually practicing for an interview or competition and that they want a fast solution, fast! (yea, no). Also see [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   They all pertain to questions that come from the site, so yes.

WDYT, burn at the stake?

---

### Progress

6/7/20 - yay, [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) is gone! In the process, we've also burninated [codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codility) (based on the same concept), and identified [competitive-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitive-coding) as the next burninate victim.

7/7/20 - [competitive-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitive-coding) is now dead. Long live competitive coding!

Comment: Textbook example of a meta tag, kill it with fire.

Comment: And the "homework" tag also went to the furnace, IIRC.

Comment: On a related note, there is also the [codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codility) tag, which would probably need its own burnination since it's similar to [leetcode] and [hackerrank].

Comment: @GinoMempin Hmm, perhaps not. There are only 19 questions. Any user with edit privileges should be able to simply remove the tag from there.

Comment: @GinoMempin ...aaaaaaand it's gone.

Comment: I’d add [tag:competitive-coding] to the same pire.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This tag absolutely should be burned, just like [all coding competition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866/the-challenge-of-burninating-hackerrank) [tags that preceded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler).

I’ve dealt with ~90% of the posts, closing a very large percentage (too broad or lacking a MCVE), the remainder were handled by others. It is now gone.

In processing these I re-discovered [competitive-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitive-coding), which is a meta tag just like `leetcode` is, only more so. It's [already been up for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396289/4642212) and is gone now too, together with 4 more online-coding-challenges tags.

Comment: Leetcode is gone! That was fast, thanks for your help! What about [tag:competitive-coding]? Are there too many questions tagged there to recommend manually editing the tags out?

Comment: We should also consider blacklisting leetcode if it makes a re-appearance (although given a certain user's tagging history with this tag, we might want to do that sooner than later).

Comment: @cs95 I seem to have a distorted sense of “too many”, that starts somewhere north of 3000. ;-) It’s only 113 posts; make sure to get off-topic stuff closed as you burn!

Comment: See [Now it's time to judge \[competitive-coding\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396289/4642212).

Comment: If we really want to get rid of it, we should consider blacklisting it. The tag was created again yesterday but deleted from the few questions popping up during the day, so it was deleted by the system last night and already created again today.

Comment: and again, currently 7 questions.... I have also seen it a few times coming and going since my last comment above.

Comment: @jps: gone again now.

Comment: thanks for the quick action @MartijnPieters, but it really comes back frequently. I already wonder if we can count how many times a tag was created and deleted.