# Burninate the [leetcode] tag again and blacklist it please

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

Again [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) raised its ugly head:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083564/multiplying-large-numbers-with-precision-issues-how-to-correctly-handle-floatin

There seems to be only a single question for now.
We'll never see any bonus or benefit for questions tagged with it, and already widely agreed about that.

Maybe consider blacklisting tag-creation for that specific tag (and others like [codechef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codechef), [codeproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeproject), et al.)

Apparently related, but no longer active:

[We need to de-leet [leetcode]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode)

Unfortunately I don't know any tool, to determine how frequently these kind of tags are deleted and recreated.

Comment: The tag was not created with the linked question but already on Saturday and as usual, curators delete the tag from these questions (or the questions itself), business as usual... I think instead of your new thread, a comment on Martijn Pieters answer would have been enough. But I agree, blacklisting would be good, the tag reappears every couple of month and it's always a pain to get rid of it.

Comment: @jps I know it wasn't created with that question linked. The OP there won't have appropriate privileges to do that.

Comment: It re-appeared again on a different question. So it seems frequent enough.

Comment: Mandatory pun: "Burninante 1337 code questions".

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426399/why-isnt-blacklisting-more-common-during-burnination . I can venture a guess that when a tag does not pop up daily or weekly after burning it, there will not be much inclination to blacklist it. So if there is proof of that happening, do add it to the burn request I'd say.

Comment: I just ran across a newly added question that used the tag, so I removed it from there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77093445/1108305.  I think this illustrates that the tag will be used unless users are prevented from using it.

Comment: @Lundin does that even count as a pun? It's directly what the site name, and thus the tag, is referring to. Unless the tag *coincidentally happens* to have exactly one thousand, three hundred and thirty-seven questions associated with it....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) tag has been blocked. Users who try to use this tag when asking a (or editing) a Question will get the following message, and will not be able to post:

> The "leetcode" tag is not allowed on Stack Overflow, please use a tag that is more descriptive of the content of your question.

Comment: Really? Do all such messages have the run-on sentence?

Comment: @khelwood that's the standard message, unless we have a more specific guidance... which isn't possible because this tag is such a catch all that nothing can be more specific.

Comment: @Braiam it still at least ought to use a period or semicolon rather than a comma - across the board. "a tag that is more descriptive of the content of your question" is also unnecessarily awkward, and perhaps misleading; I would prefer "a tag that better describes the skills or expertise needed to answer the question".

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I *think* there is some kind of *cultural* taboo in United States regarding the semicolon, dating back to the 1960s. [The style guide prohibits](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#semicolons) its use. Though Grammar Girl has never mentioned it when that was part of the subject of an episode (e.g., in a recent episode about punctuation marks); maybe she wasn't aware of it.

Comment: con't - [The Chicago Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) (6.54 through 6.58, both inclusive) treats the semicolon in a neutral way (nothing to be ashamed of)