# Why isn't blacklisting more common during burnination?

Tags: support, burninate-system, tag-blocklist

I saw this burnination post [Burninate the [leetcode] tag again please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426398/6699433) where the tag [leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) has reappeared several times.

My question is simply, why isn't blacklisting more common? Shouldn't it be the norm when the community agree that a tag should be burninated?

Comment: I know the process isn't very streamlined, and requires CM involvement IIRC; I also recall there being performance concerns if the blocklist gets too large? I hunted for a post asking about this directly and didn't find any... most of what I've learned about this comes from comments by Moderators on tag burn/ block requests.

Comment: Blacklist entries are just regex entries. I have heard the same performance claim (pretty sure from staff at least once, but arsed digging that up), but I have no idea whether that actually is the case or not. There are bigger problems here though. The tag system is suboptimal on a good day, and so are the processes for getting rid of tags, creating tags, and blacklisting them. However, the actual answer  to the question here is, because the process says blacklisting should only be done for recurring tags. Leetcode should've gotten a blacklist request by now, but it just hasn't for

Comment: reasons. That's policy though, and it is a policy the company made, which may be with the aforementioned performance concerns in mind. But imo, when we decide to kill a tag permanently, that should automatically blacklist it (preferably without needing to wait 6-8 weeks for a CM to have time), but again, the tag system just doesn't allow for that as it currently stands

Comment: There are a large number of ways the tag system could be improved, but seeing as the company is more busy throwing money out the window at AI that can and will backfire the second it gets the opportunity to, and we barely get throughput on trivial FRs and bugs (such as HTML entity bugs; there was one introduced a while ago that took _over a year_ to fix, in spite of being caused by a different bugfix, or the bug where a space was missing from some banners. Took them over two months to add a space), I doubt we'll ever see the tag system in a state where blacklisting is trivial

Comment: @Zoe Maybe you should post a little more on codidact? :)

Comment: @klutt There's nothing there for me yet

Comment: Perhaps we should resolve this issue by eliminating the supply side.